# Как сделать такую прокрутку по странице?

Tags: javascript, html

Как можно было бы сделать такую прокрутку [по странице](https://www.creatorled.vc)? В плане страница стоит на месте, а при прокрутке элементы как-то меняют свои значения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Изучайте - [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, страница все-таки не стоит на месте, прокрутка все равно идет. Такие анимации совершаются с помощью события [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event), получения значений из [scrollingElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement) и работой с [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). По этим данным на JS уже можно рисовать анимации. Выходит что-то такое:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {  
  // По этим данным уже можно что-то отрисовать
  const scrollingElem = document.scrollingElement;
  const scrollTop = scrollingElem.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = scrollingElem.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  // ...
});
```

Универсальных способов тут нет, все индивидуально. Самой лучшей идеей будет посмотреть примеры реализаций подобных сайтов. [Вот](https://css-tricks.com/lets-make-one-of-those-fancy-scrolling-animations-used-on-apple-product-pages/) неплохой пример